# Can I BEGIN a CSS selector ID or Class with an underscore?

Tags: css, naming-conventions

For example: `#_id-name {}` and `._class-name {}` I know that in the early days underscores were not allowed at all - as well as double hyphens (`--`). But is it OK and would all browsers be able to read/understand a class or an ID if it starts with an `_`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1696030 Answer: Yes, you can!

Comment: Thanks - it does look like I can: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords

Comment: I have seen the other "possible duplicate" but it only talks about using underscores. I want to know if it's OK to *start* and ID or Class name with an underscore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on `html` rather than just CSS.  Documentation:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
- [ID or NAME](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)
- [CDATA (classes)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata)

To summarize, the id must apparently begin with a letter (`A-Za-z`) and can have any other letters, numbers, underscore, or dash after that.  Practically, you can start the `id` with `-` or `_` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/y6jvs/ but starting with a number does *not* work.

While these restrictions don't appear to apply to classes which are a CDATA list, practically it seems to work the same: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/y6jvs/1/

So you get a consistent and future proof browser experience, I would try to avoid doing anything funky with IDs, class names, etc.

Comment: Mmmm... Future proof browser experience is a good thing to keep in mind!

Comment: Since HTML5 the spec of the id attribute has changed to drop the restrictions you mention. So there is no need to worry about future proofing. "The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters." https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Albin thank you for pointing to the updated specifications. In the sense that the requirements won't change we don't have to worry about future proofing, but notice that a selector starting with a number for an ID still does not work for CSS or DOM selection even though it is a valid attribute value.

Comment: Indeed. You can still match it using "#\000031" as a selector instead of "#1" however, but it's not very practical.

http://jsbin.com/jawojijuza/1/edit?html,css,output